# File upload php, get only file name

Tags: php, file-upload

Is it possible to get the filename of a file, without a complete upload

Meaning after the user chose a file, dont upload that file, just get the filename and save to database?

Comment: Yes this can be done

Comment: Is it possible to get the filename of a file, without a complete upload?- Yes, see @priya786 's answer..

Comment: @starkeen PHP scripts starts to execute after file upload completes, not before the upload, not without a complete upload.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

yes it is possible you can use the code as given below

```
$filename=$_FILES['nameofyourfileinput']['name'];
echo $filename;
```

you can echo the $filename;

**OR You can use jquery to get this value like**

```
$('#inputid').change(function(){
 var value =$(this).val();
 alert(value);
})
```

Comment: He wants before user click the submit button, I guess.

Comment: what you want to say plz tell

Comment: thank you i think this really works, because im using valum fileuploader from internet, i want to this without an upload, i want to remove the uploading time itself and just get the filename, though i cant seem to get it, the javascript is so big, but this simple php upload think got it. thank you

Answer (score 0):

ya it is possible.You can also do this before uploading the file  basename() is enough for extracting name.

```
                $next=$pfet['f_name']; //fetched file from database 

                $next1 = basename($next);
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't prevent the file upload, it simply provides a way to get the file name independent of the file contents.

Preventing file upload, is best looked at the other way: what enables uploading a file.  [The answer to that is the enctype attribute on the form tag (multipart/form-data).](https://html.com/attributes/form-enctype/)

Answer (score -1):

HTML:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
                                        Select:
                                        <input name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
                                        <input type="submit" value="Update" name="submit">
                                    </form>
```

PHP:

```
$total = count($_POST['upload']);

// Loop through each file
for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ ) {
    $fileName = $_POST['upload'][$i];   
}
```

Comment: $_POST['upload'] is not the standard global uploaded files. Why propose it?