# How do I make this code upload an image without changing the image name

Tags: php

New to this so please correct me if I am doing something wrong. I have a multiple image upload form that I cannot quite get to work in the way that I want it. Every time I upload an image it assigns the image a new name. I want to keep the name the same as the original. Any suggestions?  Here is my code.

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $j = 0; //Variable for indexing uploaded image 

$target_path = "images/"; //Declaring Path for uploaded images
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {//loop to get individual element from the array

    $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "JPEG", "JPG", "png", "PNG");  //Extensions which are allowed
    $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));//explode file name from dot(.) 
    $file_extension = end($ext); //store extensions in the variable

    $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];//set the target path with a new name of image
    $j = $j + 1;//increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array       

  if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 300000000) //Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
            && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {//if file moved to uploads folder
            echo $j. ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
        } else {//if file was not moved.
            echo $j. ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
        }
    } else {//if file size and file type was incorrect.
        echo $j. ').<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
    }
    }
}

    ?>
```

I understand that this `md5(uniqid())` is where it assigns the new id. I have tried lots of ways to stop this behaviour, but everything that I try just removes the name altogether. I would appreciate any help that is given, but please be aware that I am very new to PHP. Thanks

Comment: Hi mate, welcome to StackOverflow, check out the below link it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807449/file-upload-php-get-only-file-name

Comment: @Stephen       Yes, It is with your code  md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1].

Answer (score 0):

The if conditional could be like this :

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], "images/" . $_FILES['file']['name'][$i])) {  
...
```

so it will directly using the uploaded filename

Answer (score 0):

Check this Code...

```
  <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $j = 0; //Variable for indexing uploaded image 

$target_path = "images/"; //Declaring Path for uploaded images
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {//loop to get individual element from the array

    $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "JPEG", "JPG", "png", "PNG");  //Extensions which are allowed
    $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));//explode file name from dot(.) 
    $file_extension = end($ext); //store extensions in the variable

    $target_path = $target_path . $_FILES['file']['name'][$i] . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];//set the target path with a new name of image
    $j = $j + 1;//increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array       

  if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 300000000) //Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
            && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {//if file moved to uploads folder
            echo $j. ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
        } else {//if file was not moved.
            echo $j. ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
        }
    } else {//if file size and file type was incorrect.
        echo $j. ').<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. The only issue is that it then adds an addition .jpg to the end of the image name. For example: example.jpg.jpg. Thank you again for your help. In this case Hasta Dhana's example worked, however, I will be looking at the link that you provided as I am keen to learn.