# How would my databse grab the files in my server?

Tags: php, mysql

So I was thinking and thinking and couldn't figure it out. So I was following this tutorial which I want to implement on my site https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp and on the tutorial when the user uploads their image it sends it straight to a folder, which will obviously be in the server files. Now my problem here is, if I want to display their image somewhere on their profile when they upload it, how would I go about grabbing the image from the folder, or do I have to change the code on the tutorial so that it saves in my database? I really have no clue, and I am now officially lost and anxiety is slowly falling down my imaginary tears that are illustrated by my depressed brain, and yeah.

Answer (score 1):

You save the images in a specific folder, then save the filename in the database. Whenever you want to retrieve this file in your front-end you just take the filename from the database and link to wherever you put the file.

Comment: could you elaborate on' save the filename in the database'

Comment: Could you explain to me what you don't understand? The answer should be pretty self explanatory.

Comment: so I think i sound stupid right now but, i dont think i understood correctly, I save the filename in the database by making another column in my users database called 'examplename' and then inside the column i save the file/folder name which is located in my server?

Comment: Yes, after submitting the form, you make your php code get the filename from the uploaded file, then insert it into the database.

Comment: oh... so when they click 'upload' the image will be saved on my server folders but aswell as that I will have to make my php code grab that file name ( although I am not completely sure how to do this) and store it in the database and then when i want to display it somewhere for them what do I do... sorry.

Comment: Yes, exactly! That's what you do. You'll probably find some a good tutorial [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807449/file-upload-php-get-only-file-name)

Comment: but when I want to display that image, what do I do, could you eidt your answer to show me an example plzz